# Create an array of objects using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers

I am currently learning smart pointers and am trying to do the following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> str_array(new std::string[5]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::getline(std::cin, str_array.get()[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code simply scans 5 `std::string` objects into an array.
However, the debugger shows that the memory is not getting reserved for 5 objects:

[image: the debugger]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that `new std::string[5]` is a dynamic array allocation, and so it has no (fixed/defined/calculable) size (if you don't save it before the allocation), infact

```
auto p = new std::string[5];
std::cout << sizeof(p);
```

Will print `8` that is the size of a pointer.

And so the debugger sees that `ptr` as a pointer, and can't figure out that there are other 4 elements after the first one (and so can't figure out that is an `array`, and not just a `pointer` to a `string`)

Seems like that this is a "C++ POV", and that the debugger can have more informations, and so should be able to figure out that it is an array of `string` and not just a `pointer to string` (thanks to [@Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph))

Comment: To be fair the debugger *could* (and arguably *should*) see this, as it potentially has more information than the C++ type system. The fact that the debugger displays the pointer type as `std::string*` rather than `std::string[]` or even `std::string[5]` is a debugger QOI issue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks, added a note at the bottom, feel free to edite the answer if you think that there is more to say, i'll gladly approve and accept it